# APPPATH Not Picking Up Sub Directory Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

HI I am working on my library file but currently it can only pick up controllers files that are in the folder. I need it to be able to pick up if controller is in sub folders

library file

```
function controller($file_name){
$CI = & get_instance();$file_path = APPPATH.'controllers/'.$file_name.'.php';
$object_name = $file_name;
$class_name = ucfirst($file_name);if(file_exists($file_path)){
require $file_path;

$CI->$object_name = new $class_name();
} else {
      show_error('Unable to load the requested controller class:'.$class_name);
}
}
```

Example
controller

```
 public function __construct() {
 parent::__construct();
 $this->load->library('action');
 $this->load->controller('header'); <--works
 $this->load->controller('common/header'); <-- Not Working Not Picking up the subfolder header is file.
 }
```

Comment: if it's a library, maybe $this->load->library('xxxxxx');  Not posting an answer because don't know.  In my own code I have subdirectories and they work, eg, this works for me: $this->load->model('tank_auth/users');

Comment: why don't you take a look at CIs Loader class

Comment: I have done that now using it but still the controller function of it won't let me pick up the subfolders in the controllers

Comment: If you need to load your controllers inside each other, you did something wrong in your logic.